# I have created Postgres tables using my terminal, but pgAdmin can't find them.

Tags: pgadmin

I have created a bunch of tables using my terminal, but they don't appear anywhere in my pgAdmin. The only ones that appear are ones that I've created inside pgAdmin itself. How can I get my terminal creations to appear?

Comment: You probably just need to refresh the GUI.

Comment: Or maybe you forgot to commit the `create table` statements? (if you turned off autocommit in `psql` then this would be required)